# starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for user-id/album should contain an explicit "fields" parameter

Tags: android

I successfully Log in Using Graph Api V 2.4 by now i am trying to get  all album pics from facebook but stuck here, any help can be appriciated

```
protected void getAlbumPics() {
    /* UserID=872269919494274 */
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/{872269919494274}/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                /* handle the result */
                //?fields=photos
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // handle error
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Success response== "+response);
                }
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some user's album pictures return Unsupported get request, other work fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299444/some-users-album-pictures-return-unsupported-get-request-other-work-fine)

Answer (score 1):

First You need to add some permission on facebook Button, to get user image you can use following line of code:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends,user_photos"));
```

then in Your graph API add following code...

```
 JSONObject picture= (data.getJSONObject("picture"));
```

here is the full code:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                try {  // Application code
                                    JSONObject albums=new JSONObject(object.getString("albums"));
                                    Log.d("JSONALBUM ", ""+albums);


JSONArray data = (albums.getJSONArray("data"));
                                        Log.d("JSONDATA ", "" + data);

                                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                                            JSONObject jsonObjectPictures=data.getJSONObject(i);

//final image is String array
                     finalImage[i]=jsonObjectPictures.getString("pictures");

                                     }

                                    JSONObject picture= (data.getJSONObject("picture"));
                                    Log.d("JSONPicturea ", ""+picture);

                                    String e = object.getString("email");
                                    Log.d("Email ", e);


                                } catch (JSONException E) {
                                    E.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Log.e("JSONObject", "" + object);
                                Log.e("GraphResponse", "" + response);
                                Log.e("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday, friends,albums");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

                startActivity(i);

             Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);


            }
```

Comment: JSONObject picture= (data.getJSONObject("picture")); showing error

Comment: Tnx, now I am successfully get JSonAlbums but didnt get JSonPicture pls sir I need your help here it could save me

Comment: well, i am getting images with this code,  tell me, what type of error you are getting while parsing jsonPicture

Comment: JSONObject picture= (data.getJSONObject("picture")) showing ,int value   expected here

Comment: Tnx for reply but  JSONALBUM doesnt contain any field name Picture so it alway shows error "org.json.JSONException: No value for pictures"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89896/discussion-between-sunil-singh-and-himanshu-shekher-jha).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this Method for getting album pictures, successful only to get Album picture id,created time not Links or image url, here is my code below

```
    private void getAlbum_pics(ArrayList<String> Album_id_list) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
    params.putString("height", "400");
    params.putString("type", "small");
    params.putString("width", "400");
    params.putString("link", "link");

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/" + Album_id_list.get(0)
            + "/photos", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject();

                    try {
                        JSONArray data_array1 = object.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < data_array1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject _pubKey = data_array1
                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                            String arrayfinal = _pubKey.getString("id");
                            Log.d("pic ID ==  ", "" + arrayfinal);
                            Photo_list_id.add(arrayfinal);

                        }

                        getAlbumPictures(Photo_list_id);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).executeAsync();

}



here is method to get pics from id

    public void getAlbumPictures(ArrayList<String> newpiclist) {
    /* make the API call */
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("link", "link");
    params.putString("fieldname", "from");
    params.putString("type", "large");

    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/"
            + newpiclist.get(0), params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject newpicobject = response.getJSONObject();
                    Log.e("pics photo idss==", newpicobject.toString());
                }
            }).executeAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOYO I DONE IT LETS CHECK IT above my mistake is I didnt add field in Query so friends in New graph Api V2.4 dont forget to set fields like below demo

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
              "/" + album_pic_ids,
              new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject newpicobject = response.getJSONObject();
                        Log.e("pics photo idss==", newpicobject + "");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "link,can_tag");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```